# jesport report showing error in javafx

Tags: java, jasper-reports, noclassdeffounderror

I have created **report3.jrxml** file like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report3" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="872370a6-8d31-49c9-871a-8a5a0173946f">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM eposv1orders]]>
</queryString>
<field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="LineID" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="OID" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="OItem" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="OUnit" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="OPrice" class="java.lang.Double">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="OAmount" class="java.lang.Double">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="163" y="10" width="178" height="54" uuid="5fea8912-8166-46d3-91b3-7972f00698f1"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="36" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[ANETSYS]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
            <reportElement x="367" y="49" width="133" height="30" uuid="0dff4ebe-ad4b-4a7f-b7ff-a6c4a44324bb"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="12"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="111" height="20" uuid="4b604add-ebee-4a43-8673-10ce4779fd20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[OItem]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="111" y="0" width="111" height="20" uuid="c953ebe8-4a50-4e8b-bc0c-e466152ba1c3"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[OID]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="222" y="0" width="111" height="20" uuid="43c0a817-ead2-4533-9d42-ec294d398bfe"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[OUnit]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="333" y="0" width="111" height="20" uuid="9499195b-8afc-4aef-a43f-8e02ab913266"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[OPrice]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="444" y="0" width="111" height="20" uuid="e53372c8-5dfc-483c-a093-50ef3af56be4"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[OAmount]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="28" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="111" height="20" uuid="128898e2-3e2c-4e16-8c3b-059ff8efbd66"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{OItem}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="111" y="0" width="111" height="20" uuid="04f373fc-9df6-4a0e-9b98-4de30f8be885"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{OID}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="222" y="0" width="111" height="20" uuid="91cb7831-ec26-4324-9151-7e8ae338b9e0"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{OUnit}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="333" y="0" width="111" height="20" uuid="a8466205-7da4-4419-810a-875f93da2929"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{OPrice}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="444" y="0" width="111" height="20" uuid="94c05675-15af-45cc-8f5a-c218e59a1457"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{OAmount}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
</summary>
</jasperReport>
```

and, **PrintReport.java** file here;

```
package eposv1;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewer;

public class PrintReport extends JFrame {


Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
ResultSet rs = null;


public PrintReport() throws HeadlessException {

    }

public void showReport() throws SQLException{

 try {
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/eposv1","root","");
        String jasperReport = "C:/Users/soyut_2/Documents/etBeansProjects/EPOSv1/src/eposv1/report3.jrxml";
        InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(jasperReport);


 //Fill the report with parameter, connection and the stream reader     
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(is, null, conn);

 //Viewer for JasperReport
        JRViewer jv = new JRViewer(jp);

 //Insert viewer to a JFrame to make it showable
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.getContentPane().add(jv);
        jf.validate();
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        jf.setLocation(300,100);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

 }
```

And, this is where I click the button to show report.

```
@FXML
public void showInvoice(){
    try {

        PrintReport viewReport = new PrintReport();
        viewReport.showReport();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(OrdersFXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}
```

I also assigned the button **showInvoice()** function

But, somehow I am getting this error. Can anyone tell me what this error code shows, where am I making mistakes?
here is the error code; (Error code edited, I added new .jar files after removing .zip files)

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2338)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2822)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:804)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:301)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.<init>(ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.java:56)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:277)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:262)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:441)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:860)
at eposv1.PrintReport.showReport(PrintReport.java:55)
at eposv1.OrdersFXMLController.lambda$initialize$0(OrdersFXMLController.java:177)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you include the appache logging library in the classpath at runtime?

Comment: I did if I am not mistaken. under library folder there is **commons-logging-1.2.zip** file

Comment: `.zip` file? Usually `.jar` files are used. You probably need to extract the contents from the zip and make sure the `.jar`s are in one of the classpath roots...